# Database wal and shm in android studio

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-studio

In my android studio in data/data/com.../databases there are 3 files .db, shm.db , wal.db and when i save that .db file it is not showing any table.

While in my another mobile phone files there are only two .db, journal.db and it is showing the table and data when we save it .

i don't know why it is happening ???

Comment: If you're using **ROOM** library for db in your projects/app development, it is related to that. ROOM internally manages those three db files while **resultant db** is reflected by *.db* file itself. Consider it as some kind of cache files for ROOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the database contents, you need to downlaod all those 3 files, store them together in a folder and then you would be able to check the contents of your db.

Your problem:

You are only trying to download the .db extension file. Thats why the issue is coming!

Answer (score 0):

On later versions of Android SQLite Write Ahead logging is enabled by default.

Write ahead logging creates the Wal file, see https://sqlite.org/wal.html for more details.

When the database is closed then the contents of the Wal file will be committed to the main DB file, there is also automatic checkpointing and you can trigger it manually.

It is possible to disable it on a per connection basis, but if data does not get moved to the main db file when you application has been closed then your code is not closing the database properly.